# Pandas concat - row rotation

Tags: python-3.x

I have a timeseries dataframe containing 5000 rows (df_ohlc_OTF).
I also have a listner that receives rows 1 by 1 (df_latest_OTF_candle).
When I receive a row, I want to remove the oldest row and add the new one to the dataframe.

Right now i do this with a Concat function like this :

```
if len(df_ohlc_OTF.index)>5000:
   df_ohlc_OTF = df_ohlc_OTF.drop(df_ohlc_OTF.index[0], axis='index') # remove oldest row
   df_ohlc_OTF = pd.concat([df_ohlc_OTF, df_latest_OTF_candle]) # append new row
```

How can I speed up this process ? df_ohlc_OTF is always the same size at the end as I am performing a simple rotation and I don't think it is very fast as concat creates a copy of my original dataframe.

Any help much appreciated !

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

A much faster approach will be to treat the DataFrame as a ring buffer.  Keep a separate counter saying which position holds the oldest value, and when a new value comes in, simply replace the oldest row and increment the counter (modulo the length of the DataFrame).

Of course this means when you want to read or use the DataFrame you need to remember that it is only time-ordered in two chunks: the chunk up to and including the counter (the older data) and the rest.  This may make some computations a bit trickier, but in most cases it is probably worth it if you need performance.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks !
Ended up with this fast solution :
Update index value, Sort index, Update row values

```
if len(df_ohlc_OTF.index)>500: # rotate or append
   df_ohlc_OTF.rename(index={df_ohlc_OTF.index[0]:latest_OTF_candle.index[-1]}, inplace=True)
   df_ohlc_OTF.sort_index(inplace=True)
   df_ohlc_OTF.iloc[-1, [high, low, open, close]] = latest_OTF_candle.iloc[-1, [high, low, open, close]]
```